# pull docker from AzureDevOps on linux deployment group "not logged in" error

Tags: linux, bash, docker, azure-devops

I try to execute a few script-lines to pull the newest docker image and then recreate the container on a linux machine, which is bound to azure devops using a deployment group

The script i try to execute:

```
echo "stopping container"
docker stop brokerfrontend_prod
echo "removing container"
docker rm brokerfrontend_prod
echo "downloading latest version of container"
docker pull jccontainer.azurecr.io/brokerfrontend
echo "starting container in newest version"
docker run --restart always -d -p 80:80 --name brokerfrontend_prod jccontainer.azurecr.io/brokerfrontend
```

When executing the scriptlines one-by-one over SSH, they execute fine. with "whoami" i checked that the user, which executes the script over DevOps is the same as the one i use when i manually test.

First approach: using the "command line script"
[image]

everything works, but the "pull", which exists with this error:

https://jccontainer.azurecr.io/v2/brokerfrontend/manifests/latest: unauthorized: authentication required

So question 1 here: when its the same user executing as when i manually test, why am i not logged in to the docker container? And how would i log in using the cmd commands?

--Start EDIT
 the answer to this is to create a file with the password on the linux machine and then do this:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#provide-a-password-using-stdin

This way it works. I still hope someone has an answer for the "update_docker.sh" problem
---End EDIT

Approach 2: i download a build artifact named "update_docker.sh" to the linux machine. That part works.

This yaml is used for the script execution:

```
steps:
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Bash Script'
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: './$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_BrokerFrontend publish docker/drop/update_docker.sh'
```

(Note: "update_docker.sh" contains the same script as shown above)

He finds and executes the scriptfile just fine, but now docker seems to not find its own containers, this is the release output:

```
2020-06-17T12:08:58.6612091Z ##[section]Starting: Bash Script
2020-06-17T12:08:58.6615922Z ==============================================================================
2020-06-17T12:08:58.6616135Z Task         : Bash
2020-06-17T12:08:58.6616296Z Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
2020-06-17T12:08:58.6616460Z Version      : 3.163.3
2020-06-17T12:08:58.6616596Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-06-17T12:08:58.6616792Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash
2020-06-17T12:08:58.6617018Z ==============================================================================
2020-06-17T12:08:58.7529325Z Generating script.
2020-06-17T12:08:58.7557883Z ##[warning]Executable bit is not set on target script, sourcing instead of executing. More info at https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/bashnote.md
2020-06-17T12:08:58.7565197Z Formatted command: . '/home/jens/azagent/_work/r1/a/_BrokerFrontend publish docker/drop/update_docker.sh'
2020-06-17T12:08:58.7578128Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2020-06-17T12:08:58.7604032Z [command]/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/jens/azagent/_work/_temp/7432c884-91ba-4211-9f0a-1dc8bccc1cc8.sh
2020-06-17T12:08:58.7648299Z /home/jens/azagent/_work/r1/a/_BrokerFrontend publish docker/drop/update_docker.sh: line 1: echo: command not found
2020-06-17T12:08:58.7652597Z stopping container
2020-06-17T12:08:58.7868756Z Error response from daemon: No such container: brokerfrontend_prod
2020-06-17T12:08:58.7881494Z removing container
2020-06-17T12:08:58.8101111Z Error: No such container: brokerfrontend_prod
2020-06-17T12:08:58.8114364Z downloading latest version of container
2020-06-17T12:08:58.8335633Z invalid reference format
2020-06-17T12:08:58.8348502Z starting container in newest version
2020-06-17T12:08:58.8585902Z docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/brokerfrontend_prod" is already in use by container "8bb19349fc1e45c5d8c8bd551ea59d18521b5ca491808e1b6b588d75c06e7e3d". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
2020-06-17T12:08:58.8588270Z See 'docker run --help'.
2020-06-17T12:08:58.8614705Z 
2020-06-17T12:08:58.8635224Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '125'.
2020-06-17T12:08:58.8661489Z ##[section]Finishing: Bash Script
```

(also the first line always fails, some problem with encoding between windows and linux. The rest of the lines seem to be fine)

Here we see first "No such container: brokerfrontend_prod", but then in the end he says "'/brokerfrontend_prod' is already in use by container ". I dont get why he wont find the container, and then say that the name including a forward slash would exist, while the same script works fine manually and with the "cmd" instead of "bash".

Question number 2: what could be wrong with the "bash" task? Do i need to format the file differently?

Comment: If you list the container in your bash script using `docker ps -a`, how's the result?

Comment: Any update to your issue?

Comment: I "solved" it by using the first line of the "command line script" to write the password to a temporary file, then logging in docker piping the password into the std-in login command, and then deleting the temporary file. Not sure if docker wants me to store the password in devops on purpose to do an unattended pull, but that is how it works